# How can I avoid to get the rows of two different sections alternated?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

First of all, I'm really a newbie in Cystal Reports, so please have patience with me on this.

So, I've got to display two lists, independant, one below the other. To accomplish this, I manage to insert two detail sections, both with properties from different commands.

[image]

But the preview is not showing what I would expect...

[image]

As you may see from the highlighted rows, both lists are mixed, which is not what I'm looking for.

Could anyone tell how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior of crystal report.
Add two linked sub reports in detail sections respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display two unlinked datasets your best option is to use (a) subreport(s).

Place one command in the main report to return your first dataset which you can display in detail section.

Place a subreport with your second command in one of the report footer sections (inside the subreport you can place the dataset fields in the detail section).